# Pytests with context manager

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, pytest

I am trying to understand how to test Context managert with pytests.

I created some Class and need to count how much times was called static method `do_dome_stuff`

```
class Iterator():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def do_some_stuff():
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        return [i for i in range(10)]

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        return True

iterator = Iterator()

def f(iterator):
    with iterator as i:
        for _ in i:
            iterator.do_some_stuff()
```

I have created py.test file and need to check if function was called 10 times. But my solution isn't working:

```
@pytest.fixture
def iterator():
    return MagicMock(spec=Iterator)

def test_f(iterator):
    f(iterator)
    assert (iterator.do_some_stuff.call_count == 10)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't it be `iterator.do_some_stuff.call_count`?

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code doesn't work, is that `MagicMock(spec=Iterator)` replaces the `__enter__` method of your `Iterator` class by a `MagicMock` object, see the [MagicMock documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.MagicMock). This means that in your test, the value of `i` in function `f` is a `MagicMock` object instead of `list(range(10))`, so the code inside the for loop is never executed.

To make it work, you will probably only want to mock the `do_some_stuff` method:

```
@pytest.fixture
def iterator():
    it = Iterator()
    it.do_some_stuff = Mock()
    return it

def test_f(iterator):
    f(iterator)
    assert (iterator.do_some_stuff.call_count == 10)
```