# pytest: AssertionError inside Context Manager not raised

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, contextmanager

There are some similar questions, e.g [Pytests with context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407318/pytests-with-context-manager).  Still I don't get it.  Why is this assertion inside a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) not raised?

```
class foo:
    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        return self

def test_context_manager():
    with foo():
        assert False  # <- works outside the with statement but not here
```

Using: python3.9 and pytest6.2.5

**Update:** it works when the `__exit__` method of the context manager does not return self.  This works:

```
class foo:
    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        pass  # <- this fixes it
```

But still the question remains.  Why does the 1st case fail.  Is this a bug?  Shall I report it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A context manager is designed to catch exceptions like this and pass it to `__exit__`. If you want to raise the exception, you need to take care of it yourself:

```py
class foo:
    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        if exc_value:
            raise exc_value # AssertionError raised here
        return self

def test_context_manager():
    with foo():
        assert False

test_context_manager()
```

Comment: Ok understood.  Thanks a lot for the clarification.  Nevertheless this was a good pitfall for me.  Took me quite a while to get it straight.